# Pointing the default localhost folder to joomla in apache2

Tags: apache2, joomla

Please help me to solve this issue as I am new to apache2.

My question is how to point "localhost" default `/var/www` to `/var/www/joomla`. Because whenever I type "localhost" in the browser it shows like it works! But instead of that I want to point that "localhost" default to my joomla site folder.

Even I tried running `gksu gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1` through the terminal and point it to my sites but nothing has changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you type `localhost/joomla` in your browser, will you see your joomla site?

Comment: But i want my domain name point to www/joomla instead of typing localhost/joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These worked for me:

1. Using the terminal, start to edit with root priviledges `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file using `nano` for example:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```
2. Find the following line:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   ```
3. Replace the above line with:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/joomla
   ```
4. Save the file and close it.
5. Restart apache2 server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your healp but now problem has been solved using this command 
<i>cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1</i>